# How to plot two bar charts in the same graph using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have two bar charts on the same plot.

Let's say these two bar charts will be based on a variable `Var1` with two levels (`Var1` is a column in the table). I have the frequencies in the same table where `x` represents the counts and `y` represents different levels of interest. If I use the below code, then I get them on the same plot but it shows the results for two levels of `Var1` on the same bar for a level of `y`. I would like to have two bars side by side representing two levels of `Var1` for a level of `y`. How do I do that?  Thanks!

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,fill=Var1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: actual `data` would be rly helpful to those you're seeking help from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position = "dodge"` to the `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,fill=Var1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. This was what I needed